# I tried to use "with_items" inside when statement but failed

Tags: ansible

```
- hosts: 22rrvgndns01
  gather_facts: no
  vars_files:
    - /etc/ansible/dnschange/dns_resource_record.yml
  tasks:
- shell: grep "{{item.name}}" check_result.txt
    args:
      chdir: /cluster/dnschange
    when: "{{item.action}}" is match("delete")
    with_items: "{{resource_record}}"
```

Here is the resource_record:

```
- resource_record:
    - name: test.201.apn.epc.mnc002.mcc505.3gppnetwork.org
      record_type: naptr
      action: create
      view: MME
      ttl: 300
      order: 100
      preference: 999
      flags: s
      service: x-3gpp-pgw:x-gn:x-gp:x-s5-gtp
      replacement: wip-ows-pgw-e-NSW.node.epc.mnc002.mcc505.3gppnetwork.org
```

I got the error when I executed the script

The offending line appears to be:

```
chdir: /cluster/dnschange
when: "{{item.action}}" is match("delete")
                        ^ here
```

I could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

```
with_items:
  - {{ foo }}
```

Should be written as:

```
with_items:
  - "{{ foo }}"
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: `indentation` for the yml format is two spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your indentation is wrong and change in when condition. Can you try as below

```
- shell: grep "{{item.name}}" check_result.txt
  args:
    chdir: /cluster/dnschange
  when: item.action == 'delete'
  with_items: "{{resource_record}}"
```

Comment: ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  did not find expected key

The offending line appears to be:

      chdir: /cluster/dnschange
    when: {{item.action}} is match("delete")
                          ^ here
We could be wrong, but this one looks like it might be an issue with
missing quotes. Always quote template expression brackets when they
start a value. For instance:

    with_items:
      - {{ foo }}

Should be written as:

    with_items:
      - "{{ foo }}"

Comment: It is working now. It seems double quote is not required. Thank you so much.